Angular PrimeNG monthselector - how to highlight the current month
I am using Primeng for a monthselector
<p-calendar 
  [(ngModel)]="date" 
  view="month" 
  dateFormat="mm/yy"
  inline:"true"
  [readonlyInput]="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
    <span [class.active-month]="isActiveMonth(date)">{{date.month}}+</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-calendar>

The pTemplate part will not be triggered when it's in monthview only if the days are shown (remove the view property).
is there a way to highlight the current month when the component is loaded.
Selecting a month works fine.
Also how do you get maxdate working with months iso days

You can create a custom directive to do this, since I was not able to find a way to do it with calendar configuration.

First we create a directive, that has the current date (today), which we use .getMonth() to get the month number (starts at 0). So the month needs a monthNumber + 1 to have the correct month number.
Then we use querySelector to get the :nth-child using CSS selectors and pass in this month number, then finally using Renderer2 of angular, we add the class to the found element.
@Directive({
  selector: '[highlightCurrentMonth]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class HighlightCurrentMonthDirective {
  element = inject(ElementRef);
  renderer = inject(Renderer2);
  today: Date = new Date();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const monthNumber = this.today.getMonth() + 1;
    const monthSpan = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector(
      `div.p-monthpicker > span:nth-child(${monthNumber})`
    );
    this.renderer.addClass(monthSpan, 'active-month');
  }
}

Styles:
    .active-month {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

Full Code:
TS:
import {
  Component,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  inject,
  Renderer2,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlightCurrentMonth]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class HighlightCurrentMonthDirective {
  element = inject(ElementRef);
  renderer = inject(Renderer2);
  today: Date = new Date();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const monthNumber = this.today.getMonth() + 1;
    const monthSpan = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector(
      `div.p-monthpicker > span:nth-child(${monthNumber})`
    );
    this.renderer.addClass(monthSpan, 'active-month');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'calendar-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './calendar-basic-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule, HighlightCurrentMonthDirective],
})
export class CalendarBasicDemo {
  date: Date | undefined;
}

HTML:
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-calendar
    [(ngModel)]="date"
    view="month"
    dateFormat="mm/yy"
    inline="true"
    highlightCurrentMonth
    [readonlyInput]="true"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="month" let-date>
      <span [class.active-month]="isActiveMonth(date)">{{date.month}}+</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-calendar>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you for your answer. It's gonna work but I think its to much code/effort for just to highlight the current month  "on init". I will go trough the api once again. there has to be a simpler way for doing this because with days it works fine.
If nothing works I will consider your aswer. Thanks

The type of the date must be a string (for the calendar component)
I use the type Date. That must be converted to a string in the given format.
so I used mm/yy (primeNG formatting) which translates to "12/2024"
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'MM/yyyy');
}

The solution can be that simple :)
(for MaxDate you must use type Date)
